# Given $H \leq G$, prove a group $C(x) \leq G$ and $N_G(H) \leq G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a group and $H \leq G$ 
> a) Prove for any $a \in G$ , $aHa^{-1} \leq G$ 
> b) Let $x\in G$ and $C(x) = \{ a \in G : ax = xa \}$. Prove $C(x ) \leq G$. 
> c)Let $N_G (H) = \{a \in G : aH = Ha\}$. Show that $N_G (H) \leq G$ and $H \leq N_G(H)$.

Note: my professor uses $H \leq G$ to denote H is a subgroup of G.
As I am still very new to the subject, forgive this quiet naive and obvious question. I have read about the idea of normal subgroup in textbook, but we have not formally discussed it in class, so bare with if I miss any obviously available lemma.
I proved all three with the fact that H is a subgroup of G iff H nonempty, and $\forall x, y\in H, xy^{-1} \in H$. 
But it feels like a rather redundant way of proving it, as my guess is there is some way of using a) for b), and a) b) for c), but I cannot formulate how exactly. 
(Additional small question: I realize that $N_G(H)$ is a normal subgroup; is $C(x)$ any commonly seen group with a name?)
I am giving some of my attempts below but I do understand it is quiet messy and naive.

Attempt for c):
$\forall a \in N_G (H)$, we also have $a \in G$, i.e. $C(x) = \{a \in G: ax = xa \}$ for some $x \in G$. We have proved $C(x) \leq G$. 
As a result of a), we also have $a C(x) a^{-1} \leq G$. 
Let $y \in C(x)$, then $y = xyx^{-1}$. we now have $axyx^{-1}a^{-1} \in G$.
And for which I am stuck now...

Any suggestion and help is appreciated.

Comment: No, there is no way to use (a) for ( b) or (b) for (c). No, $N_G(H)$ is not necessarily a normal subgroup, $C(x)$ is called "the centralizer of $x $".

Comment: Please focus on one question per post.

Comment: $C(x)$ is called the centralizer of $x$ in $G$. $N_G(H)$ need not be normal in $G$; it is the largest subgroup of $G$ in which $H$ is normal.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the clarification...I guess this is thus an invalid post and I will delete it. Make sense and thanks again.

Comment: @Ningxin Thanks for the direction and answer. I will go read more about the subject matters.

Comment: Eva Lin, your attempt for c) is hard to follow. Your "$a \in G$, *i.e.* $C(x) = \{a \in G: ax = xa \}$ for some $x \in G$" makes no sense, and you do not seem to be trying to prove that $N_G (H) \leq G,$ which should begin with "let $a,b\in N_G(H),$ let us prove that $ab^{-1}\in N_G(H)$".

Comment: @AnneBauval You are actually very right in I do not know how to prove $N_G(H) \leq G$ here. My attempts seems to give me the inverse of what I want, which was why I was quiet confused and curious if there is a way I could use a) and b) for c).

Comment: @EvaLin I don't think you need to delete the post yourself. If enough people feel the need, they will vote to close your question.

Comment: @Ningxin okkkk make sense. sorry I am not that familiar with asking questions here. thanks, I will just leave it here now.

Comment: let me know if my solution is useful and give it a +1 and verify the solution. I have done your (b) and (c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a simple proof, and for simplicity I’ll show the centraliser and normalisers are subgroups of your group $G$.

**Theorem: $C_G(A),N_G(A) \leq G$ are subgroups.**

**Proof:**

Let $G$ be a group. We show $C_G(A) \le G$ where $A \subset G$. Let $x,y \in C_G(A)$, then for all $a \in A$ we have
$$x  a = a x$$
and
$$y  a = a y$$
Then
\begin{align*}
    x  y  a &= x  a  y\\ 
    &=a x  y
\end{align*}
Forcing $x  y \in C_G(A)$ and we have closure.
For closure of inverses, let $x \in C_G(A)$. Then
$$x a = a  x.$$
Hitting both sides by $x^{-1}$ we obtain
$$x^{-1}  x  a  x^{-1} = x^{-1}  a  x  x^{-1}.$$
This forces
$$a  x^{-1} = x^{-1}  a,$$
forcing $x^{-1} \in C_G(A)$. Thus $C_G(A) \leq G$ is a subgroup.

Let $G$ be a group. We show $N_G(A) \le G$.  Let $x,y \in N_G(A)$. We show $xy \in N_G(A)$ and $x^{-1} \in N_G(A)$. For closure, if $x,y \in N_G(A)$, then
$$x  A=A  x$$
and
$$y A=A  y.$$
Thus we can compute
\begin{align*}
    (x  y)  A &= x  (y  A) \\
    &=x  (A  y)\\
    &= (x  A)  y \\
    &=(A  x)  y\\
    &=A  (x  y)
\end{align*}
forcing $x  y \in N_G(A)$ and we have closure.
For closure of inverse, let $x \in N_G(A)$, then
$$x  A=A  x,$$
thus we can compute by hitting the left sides by $x^{-1}$:
\begin{align*}
    x^{-1}  A  x&=x^{-1}  x A\\
    &=A
\end{align*}
thus it follows that $x^{-1}  A=A  x^{-1}$ forcing $x^{-1} \in N_G(A)$ thus $N_G(A) \leq G$ as was desired. $\blacksquare$

**Added:** Moreover, we have that $C_G(A) \trianglelefteq N_G(A)$ is a normal subgroup. Could you prove that fact?

Also, please upvote if you deem the proof valid for future student references.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, $e\in aHa^{-1}, C(a), N(H)$, so that they are all nonempty subsets of $G$.

a) Let $x,y\in aHa^{-1}$; then, there are $h,h'\in H$ such that $x=aha^{-1}$ and $y=ah'a^{-1}$; therefore, $xy^{-1}=$ $aha^{-1}(ah'a^{-1})^{-1}=$ $aha^{-1}ah'^{-1}a^{-1}=$ $ahh'^{-1}a^{-1}\in aHa^{-1}$.

b) Let $x,y\in C(a)$; then, $xa=ax$ and $ya=ay$; from this latter, by taking the inverses, $a^{-1}y^{-1}=y^{-1}a^{-1}$, whence $y^{-1}a=ay^{-1}$; therefore, $xy^{-1}a=xay^{-1}=axy^{-1}$, and hence $xy^{-1}\in C(a)$.

c) Let $x,y\in N(H)$; then $xH=Hx$ and $yH=Hy$; from this latter, $yh=h'y$ for some $h,h'\in H$, whence, by taking the inverses, $h^{-1}y^{-1}=y^{-1}h'^{-1}$ and finally $y^{-1}H=Hy^{-1}$; therefore, $xy^{-1}H=$ $xHy^{-1}=$ $Hxy^{-1}$, and hence $xy^{-1}\in N(H)$. Note that $h\in H\Longrightarrow hH=H=Hh$, whence $h\in N(H)$, and hence $H\le N(H)$.

Comment: thanks for regurgitating my proof slightly lol